# Qt : forcing menubar in the window?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, menubar

I wonder if it is possible to force the menubar to be IN a window with Qt. I don't have a Mac, and I uninstalled several things on my Ubuntu to force Unity to don't use "global" menubars.

I'm currently making a scientific app with Qt 4.8 (and I will switch to 5.0 as soon as it will be released) (only C++/no QML) and I have a lot of menus and submenus, so it would be better if all the menus are in the window. Is there a way to deactivate a "global" menubar? Maybe with `setNativeMenuBar(false)`, but I don't have a Mac to test it.

Comment: This would not be "better" in any sense of the imagination. Just because you and @MattPhillips prefer per-window menu bars should *not* be taken as evidence that Mac OS X users have such a preference. In fact, pretty good evidence that they don't share this preference is the fact that neither of you are Mac users. You use a different platform that conforms to your own preferences for UI design. That's an important hint, one you shouldn't ignore. Don't try and override the default behavior of the platform.

Comment: The Qt team went to serious pains to *try* and respect this (though they didn't do all that good of a job). If you hack your application not to look like a Mac OS X application, you've effectively created an app that Mac OS X users won't use. I can't see how that would be good for business. The cardinal rule of UI development is not to force your own personal preferences upon your users.